# What does the letter "g" mean for some tests in pytest's output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

This may be super easy, but I can't find it in the docs. When I run `pytest` on a project, I see a bunch of dots and letters for individual tests, e.g.

```
test.py  .............g..................
```

What does the letter "g" mean here? Where is the format documented?

Comment: Do you have custom settings or pytest extentions

Comment: Probably. How do I check it?

Comment: it depends what type of env you are using, if you have a requirements.txt fie have a look in there for pytest extentions, if you are using pipenv then look in your pipfile. if you have any custom setting have a look in conftest.py that might be overidding the default output

Comment: I have these in `requirements.txt`: `pytest==4.3.*`, `pytest-cov==2.6.*`, `pytest-only==1.2.*`, `pytest-mock==1.10.*`.  Nothing seems to be overriding the default output in `conftest.py`.

Answer (score 3):

The test status with `g` is not a standard status, you must have some pytest plugins changing this behaviour or have written custom behaviours in your conftest.py files. so as a basic example of this.

**calc.py**

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**test_calc.py**

```py
from calc import add

def test_add_success():
    assert add(10, 5) == 15

def test_add_failure():
    assert add(10, 5) == 20

def test_add_success_again():
    assert add(10, 10) == 20
```

**conftest.py**

```py
def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    if report.when == "call" and report.failed:
        return (report.outcome, 'g', 'god it doesnt work')
```

So here i am overridding the default failure output from f to g. If i run this with --tb=no

```
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                   

test_calc.py .g.
```

or with -v option

```
test_calc.py::test_add_success PASSED                                                                                                                         [ 33%]
test_calc.py::test_add_failure god it doesnt work                                                                                                             [ 66%]
test_calc.py::test_add_success_again PASSED                                                                                                                   [100%]
```

So you can see the default behaviour has been changed. Unfotuntly with no access to all your source code its impossible to say what `g` means in your output as I dont know what pytest pluggins you are using or any overidding behaviour that might be in your project.

Maybe try running pytest with the -v option to see if it gives you a more verbose output explaining what that status means.

Comment: `The test status with g is not a standard status`. What are "standard" statuses? Also, it seems that that "g" disappeared on subsequent runs, which is really weird..

Comment: Yeah its strange you cannot replicate it. From the pytest --help output the following is listed `-r chars              show extra test summary info as specified by chars: (f)ailed, (E)rror, (s)kipped, (x)failed, (X)passed, (p)assed, (P)assed with output, (a)ll`